# how to fix android.support and firebase error?

Tags: java, android, firebase

this error occurred when I tried to set up my firebase with this project.
after searching...I found a solution which after then both synced and build works fine and the app run on my device.

But the problem is that:

1. I don't understand which pair version of android.support and firebase to use.
2. though the app works fine it's still showing red underlined.

Thanks for the help.
[build.gradle(project)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Or3sq.png)

[build.gradle(app)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVsFL.png)

[AndroidManifest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1BAu.png)

build.gradle(app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.collegeapp"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
    targetCompatibility = '1.8'
  }
}

dependencies {
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:15.0.0'
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
 core:3.0.2'
}
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

build.gradle(project)

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
  }
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

  }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Add the code in the question not screenshots

Comment: In general, you should just use the latest versions of everything.

Comment: @YashKrishan I just added.

Comment: mouse hover your gradle error .then it will show the problem. If you don't understand paste your hovered screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Try to use upgrade version of firebase-analtyics.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.0'
```